# Passing Props to a Functional Component that was also passed as a Param

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React with TypeScript, I am trying to pass a functional component and an array of props to said functional component as params to a container functional component that will display them.

I am just learning Typescript and React.

Here is how I thought this would work:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface FCProps{
  [key: string]: any
}


export interface DemoFCProps {
  itemArray: FCProps[],
  functionalComp: React.FC
}

export default function DisplayFCs(props : DemoFCProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        // for each item in the array 
        props.itemArray.map(
        // spread that item's properties as props to the functional component
          (item)=>(props.functionalComp(...item))
        )

      }
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

The hope was that this would allow me to call the DisplayFCs component with any component and array of props.

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayFCs from './DisplayFCs';

function Task (name: string, content: string) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p> <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
 )
};

const taskPropsArray= [
  {name: "jog", content: "Run in park"},
  {name: "walk dog", content: "Give Treat when done"}, 
]

function Project(name: string, status: string){
return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p><p>{status}</p>
    </div>
)}

const projectPropsArray =[
{name: 'Program', status: "active" }, {name: "Pilot", status:"inactive"},
]

export default function DemoProblem(){

  return(
    <>
      <DisplayFCs functionalComp={Task} propsArray={taskPropsArray} />
      <DisplayFCs functionalComp={Project} propsArray={projectPropsArray} />
    </>
  )
}
```

In case this is relevant, I am doing it this way because the website I am building has a lot of places where I need to allow for UI to filter lists. This is a simplified version of the problem where I can pass a component and a filter object and have the controls for filtering those lists appear dynamically without having to repeatedly copy and paste code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here:

1. You need to tell typescript what props to expect for the `functionalComp`. You do this by passing the props type to `React.FC` like `React.FC<PropsTypeHere>`. That makes your props definition look like this:

```
export interface DemoFCProps {
  itemArray: FCProps[],
  functionalComp: React.FC<FCProps>
}
```

2. You should let react render this for your, rather than calling the function component directly. That makes using `<MyComponent {...props} />` syntax.

```
export default function DisplayFCs(props : DemoFCProps) {
  const FunctionalComp = props.functionalComp
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.itemArray.map(
          (item) => <FunctionalComp {...item} />
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=25&pln=13&pc=35#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY5gA7GJKTdJOAMQGEACjjABnAN5U4cANoBrJAE8AXHBEwoLAOYBdFSmYKqAXyqnKdBvBZsOXOABEkICPyERRcCZSnA2IAIJQUCjKvILCItLaADSScJgArswYwBDMKAA2fLhgKsjoMAB0-AA8rhEAfMZmFtDwACZInAkZWEkpaQ7AImAZIfwiABRgEXAqjs7l7iIAlJ5xaGlqvO0wqelZOXAAvHAj04WJyWtpmdngcUQwCVDMcINxUiX1wABuVd5SX15fv3sRhV8TkCwQUhRAKDAD0+fy+gyBIDm2wqcDKq3WZy2YkKOIRRjgAHoPrCpDNHl8TDDUQSXu84mTKEYgA)

---

But this isn't all the way to your goal:

> The hope was that this would allow me to call the DisplayFCs component with any component and array of props.

To do that, `DisplayFCs` needs to be generic. Let's start with it's props.

```
export interface DisplayFCsProps<
  FCProps extends { [key: string]: unknown }
> {
  itemArray: FCProps[],
  functionalComp: React.FC<FCProps>
}
```

Here `FCProps` is a generic type parameter. Whatever that type is, this constructs a type where it requires an array of that type, and a functional component that takes that type as props.

Then you need to use that props type from a generic functional component:

```
export default function DisplayFCs<
  Props extends { [key: string]: unknown }
>(props: DisplayFCsProps<Props>) {
  const FunctionalComp = props.functionalComp
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.itemArray.map(
          (item) => <FunctionalComp {...item} />
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Which now works as you would expect

```
function Person(props: { name: string, age: number }) {
  return <></>
}
const testPersons = <DisplayFCs
  functionalComp={Person}
  itemArray={[
    { name: 'Sue', age: 30 },
    { name: 'joe', age: 24 }
  ]}
/>


function Book(props: { title: string, author: string }) {
  return <></>
}
const testBooks = <DisplayFCs
  functionalComp={Book}
  itemArray={[
    { title: 'Necronomicon', author: 'Sue' },
    { title: 'The Expanse', author: 'Joe' }
  ]}
/>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY5gA7GJKTdJOAEWAGcwAGxQBPAGIBhfgAUcYfgB4qcOFLkQFcOm2YATfnADecANoBrJKIBccfjCgsA5gF1bAV2bnmEAO7M4AF8qAD5jFSY2EABBKCgxW3V5flMXABoIzE8MYAhmFCFJXDBbZHQYADopRSTNfhCqYOpKOgZ4PSROdyEsbJhcgL5BEQlpZUpVDS0dJH1DEwsrW3tHZlcPLx9-INCACjBk2yHhMSlZZMUp+oBKcIm4NDz7NT6BgqLwOABeOAO6iqyzByeXexQiRBg7igAV2EVUij0wAAbg17qpVEY4ejVH8FBVgFFYvFRBUQCgwLC0dj0bsCUgQLcvmEaq8QYVisYKly6SBAnAAPSo6no65Y1RNbGKfmIlERUWUJpUKiA4EBGTsfh5faHYxwfIgJDLBzONJwFBOQ169wgABG7CCt0x9whUICihCUtRTUezGebHs6qgmt93zgimOIzOmVZ+XZ4C+RkDwYlkXpRLECdMWJM+st+AAyu4kPhTebLQBmAAMQQyVJzKANtnwACsIMXSxbbAAmAAsO3uLiagqVzRV-TycAAQhAIOZtXVbCZ+jAhJaViaze4YAALaBG1ZOB13VQu6Fhj3DhVUH1+pD2aezww-cMCE6jfjRoHj2MfMAJh-mCmPLpqImbZnAy6rk2ABySBoDgPggMAPolpuO57gQhbFjW4GQXmAAq27cAAovQKC+u2aG7lATYAFJtvg-aqIOVCXkAA)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I guess you just need to change your `DisplayFCs`'s map:

```
      {
    // for each item in the array 
    props.itemArray.map(
    // spread that item's properties as props to the functional component
      (item)=>(<props.functionalComp {...item} />)
    )

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to clarify what a function component is. Neither `Task` or `Project` are function components. They look like they are, but they aren't.

Most importantly to your question, a function component accepts one parameter - `props`, and is used in either JSX syntax (`<MyComp/>`) or using `React.createElement` calls (pretty rare).

Your "Function components" are just regular functions right now that happen to return JSX.

Next, `itemArray` defined in the interface of `DisplayFCs` does not match your usage where you pass it `propsArray`.

Finally, as shown in the snippet below, you should convert the two functions to be true components, and call them with JSX. Since the prop `functionalComp` does not begin with an uppercase letter, notice that I assigned it to a temporary variable that does. I've removed the typings for the snippet to run.

```js
function DisplayFCs(props) {
  // Temp variable to make uppercase
  const Comp = props.functionalComp;
  return (
    <div>
      {props.propsArray.map((item) => {
        return <Comp {...item} />
       })}
    </div>
  )
}

// Use props and access values through them
function Task (props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>{props.name}</p> <p>{props.content}</p>
    </div>
 )
};

const taskPropsArray = [
  {name: "jog", content: "Run in park"},
  {name: "walk dog", content: "Give Treat when done"}, 
];

// Use props and access values through them
function Project(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.name}</p><p>{props.status}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const projectPropsArray =[
  {name: 'Program', status: "active" }, 
  {name: "Pilot", status: "inactive"},
]

function DemoProblem(){
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <DisplayFCs functionalComp={Task} propsArray={taskPropsArray} />
      <DisplayFCs functionalComp={Project} propsArray={projectPropsArray} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<DemoProblem />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the OP was asking about a Typescript implementation!

Comment: @ArtemisPrime "I've removed the typings for the snippet to run"

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I’d be curious to see the version with them. Maybe you’d include it?

Comment: Down vote for the statement "I want to clarify what a functional component is". According to the docs, https://react.dev/learn#components . "React components are JavaScript functions that return markup"

Comment: @enjoi4life411 You're welcome to vote as you please, but you're oversimplifying a statement from the docs and are apparently believing something that is completely false. A component must be used as JSX or passed to the `React.createElement` function (what JSX does behind the scenes). If you simply call a function that returns JSX it **is not** a component.

Comment: Just posting for readers out here that hit this question.  The accepted answer describes how components are used. The invocation of the OP might be odd, but doesnt alone negatate what it is or is NOT something. I agree that calling a component  as a function is not *using* it as a component, but flat out telling someone what its *not* doesnt seem to be a solution or be too  helpful overall. FC's can accept mutliple params, again contrary to your answer. Your solution is a possible solution, but overall reasoning seems a bit "strict" and what I would say opinionated

Comment: Nope it's just not a component. A component has a lifecycle, can use hooks, etc. What is described here cannot, because it's not a component